# Django: how to sort this table

Tags: django, html-table, jquery-ui-sortable

I have the following table implemented:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
  </head>
  <body>{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <title></title>
{{ form.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}

<form action="{% url "start" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <!-- Default panel contents -->
      <div class="panel-heading">my list</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>some informations</p>
      </div>
    <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>

        <tr width="100%">
            <th align="left">1</th>
            <th align="left">2</th>
            <th align="left">3</th>
            <th align="left">4</th>
            <th align="left">5</th>
            <th align="left">6</th>
            <th align="left">7</th>
            <th align="right">8</th>
            <th align="left">9</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for Element in data %}
        <tr width="100%">
            <th align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="{{ Element.one }}" value="{{ Element.one }}"></th>
            <th align="left"><input type="radio" name="startingpoint" value="{{ Element.one }}"></th>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.two }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.three }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.four }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.five }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.six }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ Element.seven }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.eight }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Start" />
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</form>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

How do I have to modify this table to make the output sortable by clicking on the heading?

What are the prerequisites? Is there a very easy way to use the bootstrap theme as well?

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of ready jQuery plugins, try the below one which should work by calling the library and adding the class "`tablesorter`" to your table tag:-
http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo

Comment: Hello Usama Zaky, thank you. Yes, I know this class, but I do not know how to use it. Do I have to change: <table class="table table-striped"> to <table class="table table-striped" class="tablesorter"> And where to add the functions?

Comment: Hi, 
Just call the js libraries like <script src='path/to/sortable-lib.js'></script>
then to include the class into your table tag use that <table class="table table-striped tablesorter">

Answer (score 0):

What I did now:

I copied jquery-latest.js and jquery.tablesorter.js into my folder where the *.html-file is.

And I changed my code as following:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="content-type">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-latest.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.tablesorter.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $("#myTable").tablesorter(); 
    } 
); 
</script>
  </head>
  <body>{% extends 'base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
    <title></title>
{{ form.errors }}
{{ form.non_field_errors }}

<form action="{% url "start" %}" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <!-- Default panel contents -->
      <div class="panel-heading">my list</div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>some informations</p>
      </div>
    <table id="myTable" class="table table-striped tablesorter">
    <thead>

        <tr width="100%">
            <th align="left">1</th>
            <th align="left">2</th>
            <th align="left">3</th>
            <th align="left">4</th>
            <th align="left">5</th>
            <th align="left">6</th>
            <th align="left">7</th>
            <th align="right">8</th>
            <th align="left">9</th>
        </tr>

    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for Element in data %}
        <tr width="100%">
            <th align="left"><input type="checkbox" name="{{ Element.one }}" value="{{ Element.one }}"></th>
            <th align="left"><input type="radio" name="startingpoint" value="{{ Element.one }}"></th>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.two }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.three }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.four }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.five }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.six }}</td>
            <td align="center">{{ Element.seven }}</td>
            <td align="left">{{ Element.eight }}</td>
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Start" />
{% if form.errors %}
    {% for field in form %}
        {% for error in field.errors %}
            <div class="alert alert-error">
                <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
    {% for error in form.non_field_errors %}
        <div class="alert alert-error">
            <strong>{{ error|escape }}</strong>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
</form>
    {% endblock %}
  </body>
</html>
```

There is still no function on the table to sort it. What is my mistake?